# Redirect console output to a file with errors python

Tags: python, logging, console, output, sys

Apologies if this has been answered before.

I am trying to redirect my console output to a "log" file that includes any error messages. Currently I am able to send my print statements to a file using

```
sys.stdout = open(r'mydir\Log.txt', 'w')
```

My question is how do I add any error messages that may come up during my code? My script runs overnight and I am planning to have an email sent to myself with this file detailing where the (if any) error occurred, while also keeping the print statements.

Thank you!

Comment: Check out the https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Comment: In your case, I would look into the 'Logging to multiple destinations' and 'Using file rotation' sections

Comment: Probably the best way to do it is by writing your errors to sys.stderr and launch your puthon script with `python scriptname.py 2>/path/yo/log/file`, or just use the standard `logging` library

Comment: You can put that same file object on sys.stderr also. You may end up with some odd intermingling of data. If these all just status messages, start using the `logging` module instead of print. You'll get much more functionality.

Comment: great comments, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logging module is what I went with. It works way better.

`logging.info('message')` was pretty much all I did.